# name "simStatus" is not defined

Tags: python, pass-by-reference

```
def newFunction():

   global simStatus

   makeResultWrite = open ("file.txt", "w")   
   readLogFile = open("xyz.log", "r")
   checkLine = readLogFile.readline()

   while (checkLine): 

       if((re.search('^\#\s+!tpr!',checkLine))):
           if (re.search("PASSED", checkLine)):
               simStatus = "Pass"
       makeResultFile.write('{} \n'.format(simStatus))
       checkLine = readLogFile.readline()
```

The above is a part of my full code. I am trying to write the word "Pass" in the `makeResultFile`. When I compile my code, I get an error "Name "simStatus" is not defined". I am using python 3. I do not want to directly use the function `makeResultFile.write()` because I have some other dependent loops on my code. Please suggest ways to solve this error. Thank you.

Comment: You don't set a value for simStatus in the non-pass cases

Comment: `global simStatus` alone doesn't create the variable `simStatus`, you could know that if you tried it inside the IDLE. If your `if` statement never holds true, `simStatus` thus never gets defined, and your error gets thrown. To fix it, define `simStatus` inside the global namespace.

Comment: It's very bad code practice to use globals though, you should refrain from ever using them. Functions, methods and classes are so powerful concepts because they _separate implementation from interface_. This makes a) extremely modular and b) allows to abstract problems and thus the programmer to build programs with complexity beyond his grasp. Introducing gloabls removes _all_ of these advantages. It makes your code not scalable and hard to read. Don't use them.

Comment: @BenjaminJones; thank you for the Point. I wrote a very small part here and as well as I define simStatus for non pass cases in my actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should encapsulate the shared state in an object, then pass that object in.

```
class SimStatus:
  def __init__(self):
      self.status = 'Failed'

def newFunction(simStatus):
  ...
  if 'PASSED' in checkLine:
    simStatus.status = 'Pass'
  makeResultFile.write(simStatus.status + '\n')

simStatus = SimStatus()
newFunction(simStatus)
newFunction(simStatus)
```

This avoids all of the design and syntactic problems that globals introduce.  It makes it possible to use this function tracking multiple statuses at once, and is helpful in test scripts as well.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But is there any other way without using class?

Comment: The other trick is packaging it up in an array or a dictionary, something else that gets passed by reference...but what’s wrong with using a class here?